# How to run Python script in Cron in GCP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cron

I would like to get a help from you.
I am trying to deploy my python script to google cloud and execute it as cron.
I am unable to deploy it to google cloud as i am unable to it work.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In your use case, you have to deploy your python somewhere.

- If the script takes less than 1H, deploy it on [Cloud Run Jobs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs)
- If not, prepare a [Batch configuration](https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/get-started) for your script

In both case, I recommend you to use container to package your code.

Then you have to schedule that runtime.

- Call the [Cloud Run Job execution API](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.jobs/run) directly with Cloud Scheduler (*Be careful, for now, you can't send parameters to your jobs, only trigger a run*)
- Call the [Batch API](https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.jobs/create) directly with Cloud Scheduler and with the config in the body